# Разъясните смысл std::in_place, std::in_place_type и std::in_place_index для std::optional, std::variant и std::any

Tags: c++, c++17

С какой целью `std::in_place`, `std::in_place_type` и `std::in_place_index` используются для `std::optional`, `std::variant` и `std::any`? Каков принцип их работы? Если можно, с примерами.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Эти переменные-теги и соответствующие им типы предназначены для решения следующей задачи.

Пусть у меня есть

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *> v;
```

и я решил инициализировать эту переменную как

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *> v("Hello World");
```

Правила инициализации `std::variant` совпадают с правилами overload resolution (для некоей воображаемой функции). Эти правила говорят, что я в этом случае получу вариант, хранящий `const char *`. Но вдруг мне по какой-то причине нужно, чтобы литерал `"Hello World"` использовался именно как инициализатор для варианта, хранящего `std::string`.

Вот для достижения этой цели я и могу использовать `std::in_place_type` с шаблонным аргументом соответствующего типа

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *> v(std::in_place_type<std::string>, "Hello World");
```

`std::in_place_type<std::string>` в этом случае - это "фиктивный" тег-аргумент, задача которого - просто заставить компилятор выбрать правильный конструктор в процессе разрешения перегрузок (overload resolution). Больше этот аргумент ничего не делает.

`std::in_place_index` делает то же самое, только выбирая тип по порядковому индексу в списке шаблонных параметров `std::variant`

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *> v(std::in_place_index<0>, "Hello World");
```

Пользуясь этим тегами я могу делать forwarding аргументов в любой конструктор `std::string`, в том числе многоаргументный

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *> v(std::in_place_type<std::string>, 10, 'a');
// Создает внутренний `std::string(10, 'a')`
```

Вы можете заметить, что того же эффекта я мог достичь, вручную сначала сконструировав временный объект

```
std::variant<std::string, const char *> v(std::string("Hello World"));
```

но эта версия действительно сначала создает временный объект `std::string("Hello World")`, а затем *перемещает* его во внутренний объект `std::variant`. Это не всегда то, что нужно. Идея с `std::in_place_type` (и компанией) заключается в том, чтобы получить forwarding передаваемых аргументов прямо в конструктор создаваемого внутреннего объекта, без формирования каких-либо промежуточных временных объектов.

---

`std::in_place_type` также применим с `std::any` для явного указания типа хранимого объекта и c той же целью получения forwarding: сконструировать внутренний объект сразу, через forwarding аргументов, без промежуточного перемещения.

---

`std::in_place` предназначен для использования с `std::optional` и тоже вызывает именно forwarding последующих аргументов прямо во внутренний конструируемый объект. В `std::optional` выбирать тип не нужно, ибо он зафиксирован заранее, поэтому `std::in_place` не имеет никаких шаблонных параметров, т.е. является обычной переменной, а не шаблоном переменной.

Comment: Можно ещё использовать суффикс `s` из `string_literals`. Любопытно, что вариант с суффиксом при этом [получился даже лаконичнее](https://godbolt.org/z/Y2nPog) `inplace`-версии.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ в каком смысле лаконичней? Дифф же одинаковый. А вот если сделать как в ответе (просто `"Hello World"`, а не `std::string("Hello World")`), то будет чуть меньше, чем с суффиксом. А на клэнге разницы нет в обоих случаях (только 1 команда переставляется)

Comment: @dIm0n пару лет назад версия gcc-trunc была, как можно несложно догадаться, другая. Поэтому и дифф был другой. Например, если выбрать 8.3, то разницу будет сразу заметно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: Вариант с суффиксом `s` страдает от той же проблемы, которую я описал в ответе выше: он конструирует промежуточный временный объект, то есть не работает in-place. Главная задача вышеописанных тегов - предоставление возможности in-place конструирования, т.е. конструирования *напрямую* того объекта, который хранится в `std::variant` и компании. Cуффикс `s` этой задачи не решает.