# Как отличить конструкторы с одинаковой сигнатурой

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Что делать, если мой класс может иметь различные по смыслу конструкторы, но эти конструкторы имеют одинаковую сигнатуру? Как отличить их?

```
struct Circle {
  Circle(float radius, float center_delta);
  Circle(float any_point_delta, float center_delta);
  Circle(float first_point_delta, float second_point_delta); 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Кратко: а никак.

Длиннее: варианты - или добавлять третий параметр, который говорит, как именно строить объект, или написать *фабрику* - обычно статическую функцию, которая возвращает новый объект (ну, почти как конструктор :)) - и сделать их три разных с тремя разными именами.

Comment: ответ хороший, но кажется есть еще варианты...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Варианты есть всегда, а особенно в программировании. Приведенные в ответе кажутся мне простейшими. Хотите экзотики? Например, три наследника с разными именами - которые отличаются только именами! - и вуаля. Но начнутся проблемы иного рода. Так что всегда нужно вовремя останавливаться :)

Comment: тоже хороший отвтет...

Answer (score 2):

Определите перечисление, вроде:

```
enum class CircleCstType {
    byRadAndDelta,
    // etc
}
```

и передавайте его в конструктор. В конструкторе - switch.

Или же создайте фабрику для данного класса, в ней определите соответствующие методы и сделайте ее другом класса:

```
class CircleFactory {
public:
    Circle createByRadAndDelta(float, float);
    Circle createByDeltas(float, float);
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Способом решить данную неоднозначность - великое множество.

Если ограничиться только вариантами, которые выбирают требуемый конструктор на стадии компиляции, то можно это сделать, например, введением фиктивного параметра-тэга, [как это делается в некоторых стандартных классах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/850943/182825)

```
struct by_radius_and_center_tag {} by_radius_and_center;
struct by_point_and_center_tag {} by_point_and_center;
struct by_first_and_second_tag {} by_first_and_second;

struct Circle {
  Circle(float radius, float center_delta, by_radius_and_center_tag);
  Circle(float any_point_delta, float center_delta, by_point_and_center_tag);
  Circle(float first_point_delta, float second_point_delta, by_first_and_second_tag); 
};

...
Circle circle(10, 100, by_radius_and_center);
```

При желании можно вообще перейти на передачу инициализирующих значений упакованными *внутрь* класса-оболочки

```
struct radius_and_center_pair : std::pair<float, float> 
{ using std::pair<float, float>::pair; };
struct point_and_center_pair : std::pair<float, float> 
{ using std::pair<float, float>::pair; };
struct first_and_second_pair : std::pair<float, float> 
{ using std::pair<float, float>::pair; };

struct Circle {
  Circle(const radius_and_center_pair &radius_and_center);
  Circle(const point_and_center_pair &point_and_center);
  Circle(const first_and_second_pair &first_and_second); 
};

...
Circle circle(radius_and_center_pair{ 10, 100 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно еще определить структуры, имеющие операторы преобразования в тип `float`. Например:

```
struct Point {
    float delta;
    Point(float d = 0) : delta(d) {}
    operator float() { return delta; }
};

struct Points : Point {
   Points(float p) : Point(p) {}
};
```

тогда пример вашей структуры:

```
struct Circle {
  float x, y;
  Circle(float radius, float center_delta)
      : x(radius), y(center_delta){}
  Circle(Point any_point_delta, Point center_delta)
      : x(any_point_delta), y(center_delta){}
  Circle(Points first_point_delta, Points second_point_delta)
      : x(first_point_delta), y(second_point_delta){}
};
```

и пример создания обьектов:

```
Circle c1(2.0, 3),
        c2(Point(0.5), Point(1.5)),
        c3(Points(2), Points(3));
```

P.S. И как сказал пользователь `Harry`, варианты есть всегда(по мне не всегда, а почти всегда)...

Comment: Неявные преобразования - зло. Особенно эпично будут смотреться варианты типа `c4(0.5, Point(1.5))` и `c5(Point(0.5), Points(1.5))`.